# Is Webmin recommended for recent releases of Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04

About Webmin, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webmin) mentions that:

> "The best supported systems at the moment are Solaris, Linux (Red Hat
>   in particular) and FreeBSD"

My question is, does anyone have experience with webmin under Ubuntu (10+ releases)? Would you recommend it? If not, is there a 'good' alternative to Webmin for Ubuntu? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We're using Webmin and Virtualmin on our Ubuntu 10.04 LTS servers without an issue. We normally add it via the [Webmin APT Repository method](http://www.webmin.com/deb.html). Webmin makes my admin life easier :)

Answer (score 3):

Yep, use it on 10.04, 10.10, 11.04 without any issues.

FYI Virtualmin only supports LTS releases.